# Console won't show up

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, codeblocks, sfml

I'm using CMake with SFML. I open up the generated cobeblocks project and create a new main.cpp file inside the `Main` directory under `Source` parent directory generated by cmake. Then I click "Build and Run". It seems to everything but compile the code. The console also doesn't show us even though I set the build type to console application. How can I fix this?

Comment: Some IDEs will redirect the application console to one of its own windows.  Is there a "Program Output" or "Program Console" window inside Code::Blocks?

Comment: Try adding a statement to input data before the end of your `main` function.

Comment: `Project->Properties : Build targets tab - [ ] Pause when execution ends.` Ensure you have this check-box ticked.

Comment: @enhzflep Still doesn't do anything.

Comment: @BenVoigt No, there's not.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Like I said it doesn't even compile the code. I don't know why.

Comment: Turn on all the errors & warnings to maximum.  Append all error output to a single text file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My file can contain non-sense, like `int main() = [][gfsgf\[fgfsgf[]]l blah blah blah` and it will still build and run. Maybe I'm not setting it up right.

Comment: @templateboy - that doesn't sound right.Are you sure there's nothing of note visible in the Build Log or Build Messages tabs of the output pane after trying a build. (F2 brings up the pane, or View->Logs) Also, do you know that you have MinGW or GCC installed and that the IDE knows where to look for it? "sudo apt-get install codeblocks" only gets the IDE if in linux, and the windows version can be downloaded with/without the compiler. You can check the Settings->Compiler menu option to check if it knows where the compiler and it's tools live.